# Title bar with close, minimize, and maximize dialogue options dissapeared after update

Tags: windows, 12.04, titlebar

Running Ubuntu 12.04 
During installation of a few programs (Gparted and some others) my computer unexpectedly shut down.
When I restarted my machine everything appeared normal. However, every program I open, whether it be terminal or Firefox, the title bar is missing. In other words there is no window dialogue other than File, Edit, View, etc... I don't have the option to close, minimize or maximize.
In addition to the absent title bar things don't seem to load quite right. For example, when I load Firefox and go to google.com search results seem to be improperly underlined/not underlined at all. Picture quality is not bad; things just don't load fully/corrupted looking textures and graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Log in with Unity 2D, open `ccsm` (Compiz config settings manager) or download it with `sudo apt-get install ccsm` and go to **Preferences** at the bottom and choose *Reset to defaults* and then choose *Unity* from the list. Then you can log in into Unity 3D (the normal one) and everything works :)

I had this error today too and that worked for me.
**Notice:** Probably you have to log in with Unity 3D to change the settings, I am not totally sure anymore. But give both a try ;)

---

**Thanks to [Ryan McClure](https://askubuntu.com/users/46672/ryan-mcclure) for this addition:**

If by any chance Unity 2D has the same issue (it happened to me once before, so I can relate :P) and neither shell does not allow you to open terminal, press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to open a TTY session. From here, enter your username and password and continue to do the commands thonixx gave you.

Comment: If by any chance Unity 2D has the same issue (it happened to me once before, so I can relate :P) and neither shell does not allow you to open terminal, press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to open a TTY session. From here, enter your username and password and continue to do the commands thonixx gave you. Great answer btw @thonixx :)

Comment: Thanks Ryan :) I'm doing my best sharing my experience for other users.

Comment: I don't know what's going on...but I did the Ubuntu 2D at login and when it booted up it looked terrible. I don't even know how to describe the poorness of quality...black screen, the launcher was a mess...so I did the ccsm thing in regular Ubuntu and then when I rebooted and logged in (into normal Ubuntu) and the launcher and the taskbar thing at the top are completely gone...I have my wallpaper though :P

Comment: What commands are you referring to?

Comment: Go to `ccsm` -> Preferences -> Press Restore to defaults -> Reboot -> Go to `ccsm` -> ("Default" should be selected now") Change it to "Unity" -> Reboot **If** this does not work please post a comment.

Comment: Then why am I in a tty? It won't load ccsm from there. and when I login to ubuntu there is no way to launch programs, can't open terminal through ctrl+alt+t and there is no launcher or taskbar at the top of the screen. In ubuntu 2D I can't see ANYTHING when opening a program.

Comment: Then do `sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal`, go into Unity and right click on the desktop and choose "Open in Terminal". That was my way to do it.

Comment: Ok :) and from terminal run ccsm?

Comment: I launched ccsm and selected "reset to defaults" i rebooted and when I launched ccsm again "Unity" was still the selected profile...it didn't change to "default"

Comment: Then try to select "Default", reboot and select "Unity" and reboot. If this won't help you could reinstall CCSM but I think it would be more useful to reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` package with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-deskop`.

Comment: I tried reinstalling both ccsm and ubuntu-desktop. Still, no launcher or taskbar :\
Also, i tried logging into a guest session and everything was there (except the title bar in open windows)! Why is it only on my account??

Comment: Seems to depend on your configuration. Try to take the configuration of another account (just those for Gnome and Compiz and all desktop related)

Answer (score 0):

After running Pinta on 12.04 today, my windows borders and title bars disappeared.
I got them back running CCSM - Effects - Window decoration: turn `off` and `on` again.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, when this would happen, we would simply run `/usr/bin/compiz-decorator --replace` from the run dialog.

An easier way was to use `fusion-icon` from the repository, which is an icon that enables, disables, and restarts Compiz, and change the currently used window manager and/or window decorator.

By the way, it's the window decorator that is in charge of the titlebar, etc.