# Unable to access window controls on maximized windows

Tags: unity, compiz, window-buttons, titlebar

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 but an annoying error has been bothering me. I formatted my PC to get rid of it, but about 2 hours after the fresh install, it came back.

The thing is that the title bar of any window, at the upper-left side, where the "close, minimize and maximize" buttons are, disappears when the mouse cursor is set over them. This disables the possibility of using them when the windows is maximized (full screen) but not when it's not. But it is very annoying.

The second screenshot may help show what I'm trying to say (notice the cursor and what happens when I try to click the close button on any window)

[image: http://ubuntuone.com/1rwdGnLgXOQysJKEdtsK6j]

This is the problem:

[image]

I'm aware that there is a [similar question answered on this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125691/title-bar-with-close-minimize-and-maximize-dialogue-options-dissapeared-after), but the thing is that the solution in that post involves using Unity2D, which was removed in Ubuntu 13.04

I hope there's a way to fix it.

Comment: I think you should open a bug report. Filing a new bug report will also automatically send many useful information required to track down the problem.

Comment: The close, minimize and maximize buttons only disappear when the cursor is set above them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am experiencing the exact same problem.

Window controls disappear if windows are maximized and I mouse over the controls.

minerz029 posted the following workaround:

> Fixed by opening a logout or shutdown dialog in Unity with Ubuntu 13.04. Opening a dialog > and cancelling it will fix the problem.

[Link to minerz029's post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322361/cant-use-window-controls-on-maximized-windows)

Comment: Is there some rational explanation for this problem and its solution?

Comment: @PabloViollier I think this is Steam related (I see a Steam icon in your tray and I also use Steam). This can also be fixed by restarting Steam. The reason a logout dialog works is because that also quits Steam (for whatever reason)

Comment: @PabloViollier See my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/329678/176889